# SQL query empty field, select ALL option like *

Tags: php, mysql, sql

A php search page uses an SQL query to search for properties based on set criteria, in the example below the street "Harrison Road" is chosen:

```
search.php?city=1&rooms=3&rooms_upper=7&price_lower=55&price_upper=100&streetname=Harrison%20Road
```

I am looking for a way to leave the streetname blank and still SELECT ALL records as below:

```
 search.php?city=1&rooms=3&rooms_upper=7&price_lower=55&price_upper=100&streetname=
```

I tried using the ' * ' symbol as with other SQL ocmmands to specify SELECT ALL but it does not work in this instance.

The problem is the search does not display any results while the street option is left blank.

The reason I am looking to run a search with an empty street criteria is because the search.php loads before the user selects a particular street using the drop down option on the page.

I would like it to SEARCH ALL records using the first criteria specified: 
rooms, rooms_upper, price_lower, price_upper

The standard search page load has been left with the widest search criteria possible ( 3 < rooms < 7 ) and (£55 < rent < £75) in order to display ALL records before the user narrows the search criteria specifying a particular 'streetname' if desired.

Many Thanks!
Jeanclaude

The full SQL is here:

```
    $sql=mysql_query("SELECT main_table.housenumber, main_table.housenumber, main_table.streetname,
                      max(main_table.rent) AS reviews_rent, main_table.rooms AS reviews_rooms,main_table.average, 
                      houses.houseID, houses.path, houses.rooms AS houses_rooms,houses.rent AS houses_rent
                    FROM main_table 
                      LEFT JOIN houses ON main_table.housenumber = houses.housenumber 
                           AND main_table.streetname = houses.streetname
                    WHERE main_table.streetname='$page_streetname' 
                        AND main_table.city=$city 
                        AND main_table.verify='1' 
                        AND main_table.rooms>='$rooms' 
                        AND main_table.rooms<='$rooms_upper' 
                        AND main_table.rent>=$price_lower 
                        AND main_table.rent<=$price_upper
                    GROUP BY main_table.housenumber, main_table.streetname 
                    ORDER BY average DESC, houseID DESC, reviewID DESC;");
```

I want to keep streetname in the WHERE clause, but I don't want to restrict the search if it is left blank.

Comment: We would really need to see how you are creating and using the SQL in the query itself. It could be changing the join types, or changing the where clause or a myraid of other things.

Comment: Then don't use `streetname` in your `where` clause.

Comment: Do you want to select `where streetname = blank` or what ?

Comment: updated with SQL and still want to keep streetname in the WHERE clause if possible, but not to use it in the search if kept blank.  I'm writing an IF statement to give two options of the $sql code.

Option I: streetname left blank, not to include it in WHERE clause.
Option II: streetname given, use streetname specificed in WHERE clause.

But i'm not sure this is the best way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's easily solved with PHP (no need for `sprintf()`):

```
<?php

$page_streetname = empty($page_streetname)
  ? null
  : "AND main_table.streetname = '{$page_streetname}'"
;

$result = mysql_query(
  "SELECT
    main_table.housenumber,
    main_table.housenumber,
    main_table.streetname,
    max(main_table.rent) AS reviews_rent,
    main_table.rooms AS reviews_rooms,
    main_table.average,
    houses.houseID,
    houses.path,
    houses.rooms AS houses_rooms,
    houses.rent AS houses_rent
  FROM main_table
    LEFT JOIN houses
      ON main_table.housenumber = houses.housenumber
        AND main_table.streetname = houses.streetname
  WHERE
    main_table.city = '{$city}'
    AND main_table.verify = 1 
    AND main_table.rooms >= '{$rooms}'
    AND main_table.rooms <= '{$rooms_upper}'
    AND main_table.rent >= {$price_lower}
    AND main_table.rent <= {$price_upper}
    {$page_streetname}
  GROUP BY
    main_table.housenumber,
    main_table.streetname 
  ORDER BY
    average DESC,
    houseID DESC,
    reviewID DESC"
);

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

How about creating the query dynamically.

Set up the base query without the streetname in the WHERE clause but include a sprintf string tag.
Then if $page_streetname has a value add the streetname selection to the query dynamically or if not just add nothing.

```
$q = "
SELECT main_table.housenumber, 
       main_table.streetname, 
       Max(main_table.rent) AS reviews_rent, 
       main_table.rooms     AS reviews_rooms, 
       main_table.average, 
       houses.houseid, 
       houses.path, 
       houses.rooms         AS houses_rooms, 
       houses.rent          AS houses_rent 
FROM   main_table 
       LEFT JOIN houses 
              ON main_table.housenumber = houses.housenumber 
                 AND main_table.streetname = houses.streetname 
WHERE  %s
       main_table.city = $city 
       AND main_table.verify = '1' 
       AND main_table.rooms >= '$rooms' 
       AND main_table.rooms <= '$rooms_upper' 
       AND main_table.rent >=$ price_lower 
       AND main_table.rent <=$ price_upper 
GROUP  BY main_table.housenumber, 
          main_table.streetname 
ORDER  BY average DESC, 
          houseid DESC, 
          reviewid DESC";

$q = isset($page_streetname) 
          ? sprintf( $q, "main_table.streetname = '$page_streetname' AND " )
          : sprintf( $q, '');
```